# Drawing on Canvas (Android)

Tags: android, android-canvas

Setting BitmapShader for Paint

```
fogShader = new BitmapShader(bg_fog, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
fogPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
fogPaint.setShader(fogShader);
```

then

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bg, 0, 0, null);
```

then

```
fogPaint.setAlpha(120);
canvas.drawRect(0, 0, width, height, fogPaint);
```

then I need to draw few circles with different `alpha`, without Rect's alpha influence. But when I draw:

```
fogPaint.setAlpha(0);
canvas.drawCircle(x, y, radius, fogPaint);
```

Rect displayed in the circle.

Comment: Check this official documentation http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html

Answer (score 0):

Create a class extending View and override onDraw(Canvas) function